# How to Bind a Plugin to a Keypress

Tags: lua, vlc

I am writing a simple Lua plugin for VLC that records a timestamp of a user defined place in a video to a text file.

There are existing plugins that do something similar, like [Moments Tracker](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154020) and [VLC Permanents Bookmarks](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1718547/) but they show a little custom GUI window with buttons to trigger the timestamp capture.

I will need to make frequent timestamps and using my index finger to continually click a mouse button for 25 minutes - 90 minutes would be fatiguing. I am wanting to bind my "capture timestamp" functionality to a keypress in vlc -- a much easier and less fatiguing target than a mouse button.

I have combed through various forums and docs and can find no way of doing this. Is there a way?

Any help (even a "you can't do that") would be appreciated.